# Creating a delta live table for reading incremental data

Tags: azure-databricks, delta-live-tables

I have a table "x" which contains raw data in bronze layer. I have another table "Y" which is in silver layer and contains the transformed data. Now the incremental data is coming in the table x and I want to merge the incremental data from table x in bronze layer to table Y in silver layer.
So I want to build a Delta live table for doing this.

Comment: the same as for original question - post the code & more details

Answer (score 0):

First exploded the data from the bronze table into a temporary table, and then flattened the data into another temporary table. Then load the data into my silver table using merge operation.

Kindly go through the [**official documentation**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/workflows/delta-live-tables/delta-live-tables-quickstart#sql). I followed the same scenario with the sample code in my environment. I added a silver table it's working fine for me without error and created a delta live table.

For more **information** refer this [**link**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BIxwoO65ylY&t=631s) it has detail information above delta live table with incremental load.